# unable to receive push message for production apns

Tags: ios, notifications, push, apple-push-notifications

I can receive push message using development cert, however when I change to use the production cert, no message can be received, and there is no error occurred.

The apns address I used is: ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195
And I test it as ad-hoc deployment

As my app is not yet uploaded to app store, so may I know if this will affect the app to receive push message?

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer now, when archiving the project, I need to use the production distribution cert. Then the production device token is generated for push notification.

Using this device token can send push to the device by production APNS.